# How can I use Json to pass a url from an web API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I converted two api extensions using jsontocsharp online converter. Through first API the classes are used to search a particular book in a button click. After given an input in the textbox a list of items will be displayed. When user clicks on a book it will navigate to other page with a download button. The second api class shows details of the book.

I can successfully show the search items and display them in next page. But how to use this download attribute from the class and link it to the selected book. So that when user clicks on download option it should be navigated to web browser and should download the respective file.

I am using it-ebooks api. Please refer this link to get details about the api.[API link here](http://it-ebooks-api.info/)

```
private async void  search_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            pgbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            var uri = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/{0}";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(uri, tb1.Text));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var listdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data.Result);

                if (listdata != null && listdata.Books != null && listdata.Books.Count > 0)
                lv1.ItemsSource = listdata.Books;
            }
```

I need to use another API for downloading the selected book.

```
private async void download_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var uri = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book{}";

       //Here I should implement some code to convert from json to simple download url
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));
    }
```

[image: This is my new page]

[image: This is my main page]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]
I should display the title and description in next page. So I binded listview control in new page. I should also download the book of the selected book

I got the below exception
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what type of component is lv1? is it listview?

Comment: Yes listview.  This download event is in new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the listview SelectedIndexChanged event handler for getting to know the selected item(s) and then convert each of the item(s) to the Book Object. Since you are assigning the list "Books" to the list view then you can extract individual "Book" object(s). See comments in the code also.

```
private long bookid;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic bookDetails = e.Parameter;
    bookid = bookDetails.ID;
}

    private async void download_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var id = bookid;

        var uri = "http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/"+id;

       //Here I should implement some code to convert from json to simple download url
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main problem is the above code is in first page. So when I click on selected item the page navigates. Using e.parameter I displayed the details of the book. The download button is in second page. How to show that particular id of the book in new page

Comment: can you show the code on how you navigate to the second page?

Comment: i am thinking, what you can do is extract the object before you navigate to the next page and pass the object as a param -- PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = param

Comment: ` private void lv1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            lv1.SelectedItem = sender;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1),lv1.SelectedItem);
        }`

Comment: i updated my answer above, please try now see if it works for you. I am not so much familiar with Windows Phone Dev but should be quite close.

Comment: bookDetails value is null...No parameter passed to bookDetails

Comment: do you mean NavigationEventArgs e is null? if not null then what is passed in? you would also need to check in your search page whether lv1.SelectedItem is null or not.

Comment: In my search page it is not null. The selected value is stored. But in OnNavigatedTo when I debug the value it shows null. I also tried other code.  `var str = e.Parameter as object;` This statement is to display the description and title. So how to extract id from str

Comment: Sorry didnt understand. Can you please post what you see in the string?

Comment: (bookDetails = e.Parameter as BookDetails ) Here when I debug the bookDetails value is null

Comment: So it seems that the parameter is returned as list of book details. If that is correct then you can take the first item.  Var books = e.Parameter as ListDa; books.First () to get the single object and extract id

Comment: When debugging what is the type of object? Does it show as ListDa?

Comment: So how to extract the single book details after this statement `var books = e.Parameter as object `

Comment: Before that can you please post what is the underlying type of listdata.books that you are assigning to the listview. I assume it is List <Book>,  if that is correct then you should use e.Parameter as Book

Comment: are you using .net 4.5? then you can use dynamic keyword. try this dynamic book = e.Parameter; then just try book.ID .. since you will use dynamic keyword there would be no intellisense in VS but you should be able to retrieve your data.

Comment: Updated my question with exception. Even now id is null

Comment: there is a problem in your code.. define above "OnNavigateTo" function,         private dynamic books; and in the navigateto function, define "books = e.Parameter;"

Comment: Your idea works. But the URI passes ID of the book to download. It downloads ID.json file when I click download button.  But the download url is present in another class (Not in Book). When I try to write `books=e.Parameter as ListData //ListData is another class with download` it shows exception. I updated in my question

Comment: So once you have the id. You would need to make another request to get the book object or json file then parse that info to get the download link.  As what you have retrieved from the server in the first query is the search results.

Comment: I am not in front of the computer but later will show you how.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. By deserializing the ID I can download the file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will pass the book id from search listing page to book detail page

```
     //Class for book details

    public class BookDetails
    {
      private string Error {get; set;}
      private string Time {get; set;}
      private string ID {get; set;}
      private string Title {get; set;}
      private string SubTitle {get; set;}
      private string Description {get; set;}
      private string Author {get; set;}
      private string ISBN {get; set;}
      private string Year {get; set;}
      private string Page {get; set;}
      private string Publisher {get; set;}
      private string Image {get; set;}
      private string Download {get; set;}
    }

    private async void download_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string downloadbookurl=string.empty;

       //Download the book detail using API http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/2279690981
         string result=GetResult("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book{book_isbn}")
       //Deserialise the json data
         BookDetails bookDetails= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookDetails >(result);
         if(bookDetails!=null)
                downloadbookurl=bookDetails.Download ;

         }
          //Launch the webview
                 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(downloadbookurl));
    }

    private async string GetResult(string url)
    {
         string response=string.empty;
         using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
         {
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(uri, tb1.Text));
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
             var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             response=data.Result.ToString();
            }
         } 
    }
```

Comment: The return type of async should be void but there it is string. How should I remove this error

Comment: `private async string GetResult(string url)
    {
         string response=string.empty;
         using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
         {
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(uri, tb1.Text));
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
             var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             response=data.Result.ToString();
            } 
         }  return response;
    }`

Comment: return response parameter from GetResult function

Comment: the return type should be Tasks<string>

Comment: When I debug the code it shows the Uri is empty. The link is not passed (i.e result) to the launcher

Comment: Please add your code, inside download_btn_Click method as a comment here

Comment: My search box is in first page and the download button is in second page. How to pass this selected book id in order to download the book.

Comment: From result you need to do Parsing and obtain BookDetails object. then get the download url

Comment: In search page. Frame.Navigate(book_detail_page, bookisbn);
In book detail page in OnNavigatedTO method protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
string bookid=e.parameter as string;
}

Comment: Please check my code I am confused. I uploaded it to github. https://github.com/lagishetty/webapi

Comment: private void lv1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
ListView listview=sender as Listview;
           Book book=listview.SelectedItem as Book;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1),book.Id);
        }

Comment: Declare a global variable bookisbn in BlankPage1.
in OnNavigatedTo method
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            bookisbn = e.Parameter as string;
        }

Comment: In GetResult method change  var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); that statement to  response1= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I displayed the title and description passing the object parameter(listview1.SelectedItem). So is it possible to pass both the objects. Simultaneously The title and desc should also dispalyed..

Comment: How to map the id of the book to the download button